# Why do we set the least significant bit as part of converting a 64-bit unsigned integer to a 32-bit float on x86?

Tags: c++, assembly, clang, x86-64, floating-point-conversion

```
#include <cstddef>
float cast(size_t sz){return sz;}
```

Compiling the above code on Clang 13.0.1 with `-mavx2 -O3` produces the following code:

```
cast(unsigned long):                               # @cast(unsigned long)
        test    rdi, rdi
        js      .LBB0_1
        vcvtsi2ss       xmm0, xmm0, rdi
        ret
.LBB0_1:
        mov     rax, rdi
        shr     rax
        and     edi, 1
        or      rdi, rax
        vcvtsi2ss       xmm0, xmm0, rdi
        vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        ret
```

Similar code is also produced on GCC, MSVC and the Intel compiler, and for older versions too.

I understand the general goal of the algorithm is to work around the fact that there is no conversion instruction from a 64-bit unsigned int to float or double, until AVX-512.

So if the number is large enough to be interpreted as negative, it halves it, converts it, and then doubles it. However, what is the purpose of setting the least significant bit if it was set in the original integer?

It seems like a waste of time since the floating point number only has 23 significant bits, and this bit is guaranteed to not be significant. Perhaps if it were an increment instruction instead, it could affect the significant bits in some cases. But just an or instruction doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: There is a default standard rounding convention on floating point numbers that >=0.5 in the least significant bit is rounded away from zero else it is truncated towards 0. Code generated may change if you select an alternative FP rounding strategy.

Comment: As an example, consider if the input is 0x8000008000000001

Comment: There are no casts in the code in the question. The question is about a **conversion**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: Right-shift ORing the LSB rounds instead of truncating.  It's *not* adding, it's just ORing, so it doesn't add if that would propagate a carry to higher bits.  And it's not unconditionally setting, it's only doing so when the LSB was set. So is this like round with odd (instead of even) as a tie-break?  That should uniformly distribute the rounding error for numbers with random low 2 bits.

Answer (score 7):

You are making an assumption that the bottom bit can never matter - this isn't true. There are a few corner case values in conversions where the bottom bit *does* matter. Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint64_t start = 0x8000000000000000;

    for(uint64_t i=start; i<(start+0x10000000000000ull); i+=0x1000000ull)
    {
        float f = (float)(i);
        float g = (float)(i+1);
        if (f != g)
        {
            std::cout << "From = " << std::hex << i << " we get " << std::hexfloat << f << " and from " << (i+1) << " we get " << std::hexfloat << g << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This iterates through a number of large values and prints out (using the handy hex float modifier) when the bottom bit makes a difference. It shows that there are a few which need this adjustment:

```
From = 8000008000000000 we get 0x1p+63 and from 8000008000000001 we get 0x1.000002p+63
From = 8000028000000000 we get 0x1.000004p+63 and from 8000028000000001 we get 0x1.000006p+63
From = 8000048000000000 we get 0x1.000008p+63 and from 8000048000000001 we get 0x1.00000ap+63
From = 8000068000000000 we get 0x1.00000cp+63 and from 8000068000000001 we get 0x1.00000ep+63
From = 8000088000000000 we get 0x1.00001p+63 and from 8000088000000001 we get 0x1.000012p+63
From = 80000a8000000000 we get 0x1.000014p+63 and from 80000a8000000001 we get 0x1.000016p+63
...
```

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/jTeo1Ko4s

Comment: It would be good if you could explain why it matters. To my understanding, it matters if you end up with a mantissa ending in exactly 0.5, in which case it would be rounded to the nearest even number (by the default rounding mode). Then setting the last bit would make it greater than 0.5, and make it round upwards. This needs to be done because the last bit was removed by the shift instruction, so numbers that should round upwards might otherwise incorrectly round downwards.

Comment: @SeaErchin: we're talking about very large integers here, when the large integer without its last bit is exactly between two possible floating point representations. If the last bit of the original integer is 0, then there is nothing to be done, because the shifting doesn't change the fact that the original integer was exactly halfway (therefore the rounding result will be correct). But if the last bit was 1, then the original integer is not exactly halfway but a little bit larger. So the number has to be rounded upwards. The effect of that "or" operation is exactly this.